# Can someone help me work out this error

Tags: python, if-statement, split

This is my code, it is writen in python version 2.7.13:

```
import random
num=random.sample(range(1,9),4)
print(num)
thing=1
while thing==1:
    while thing==1:
        Usernum=str(input("Input a number of four DIFFRENT digits all of which are between 1 and 9 or exit"))
        if Usernum = "exit":
            print("Goodbye")
            break
        else:
            pass
        if len(set(Usernum)) == 4:
            pass
        else:
            print("You enterd a number that wasn't 4 digits, please try again!")
            thing==1
            pass

        if Usernum.isdigit:
            pass
        else:
            print("you entered something that isnt a number, please try again!")
            pass
        num1,num2,num3,num4 = Usernum.split() 
        if num1 in (num2,num3,nub4) or num2 in (num3,num4) or num3==num4:
            print("you ented a number with duplicate digits, Please try again!")
        else:
            break
else:
pass
```

Before i am getting a  error which I have never seen before. It says:

> "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

Comment: here `if Usernum = "exit":`

Comment: There are *many* errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to double check your equalities. In python, and many other languages, double equals `==` is a logical test. A single `=` is an assignment. Double check this through your code.

Also on the last line you have not indented your pass properly, but as you have this right everywhere else I assume this is because you aren't finished yet. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

On line 26 you want to be testing for equality between num3 and num4 like this:

num3 == num4

Note the use of whitespace between the variable names and the operator, and the use of the double equals.